# Retrieve Multiple Enitiies in Dynamics CRM using OData

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I have a ribbon button command which executes a javascript function and passes in the selected rows in a grid. I am looping through that list to create a $select filter to make a RetrieveMultiple request.
The problem is everytime I get the following error

400: Bad Request: No Property 'id' exists in type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity' at position 1

I have tried with `id` instead of `Id` but I still get the same error.
My code is below

```
function approveMultipleApplications(selectedApplicationReferences) {
    if (selectedApplicationReferences && selectedApplicationReferences.length > 0) {
        var filter = '';
        for (var i = 0; i < selectedApplicationReferences.length; i++) {
            filter += '(id eq guid\'' + selectedApplicationReferences[i].Id + '\')';
            if (i < selectedApplicationReferences.length - 1) {
                filter += ' or ';
            }
        }

        var options = "$select=new_assessmentcount,new_requiredassessmentcount&$filter=" + filter;
        try {
            SDK.REST.retrieveMultipleRecords("new_application", options, retrieveApplicationsCallBack, function (error) {
                alert(error.message);
            }, retrieveComplete);
        }
        catch (ex) {
            Xrm.Utility.alertDialog('Something went wrong, please try again or contact your administrator ' + ex, null);
        }
    }
    else {
        Xrm.Utility.alertDialog('You must select at least one application to approve', null);
    }
}
```

The selectedApplicationReferences[i].Id is in this format `{guid-value}`
Any help or guidance is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is pretty much spot on: Use *LogicalNameId* instead of just *Id*. In your case that would be *new_applicationId*:

```
filter += '(new_applicationId eq guid\'' + selectedApplicationReferences[i].Id + '\')';
```

It can be a bit confusing since there is actually no *Id*-field in the database. If you use e.g. early bound classes, the *Id* field is set for you behind the scenes, so that might have confused you. The *Id* field is not returned by the OData endpoint.

Comment: Thanks, basically the Id field is <entity_logical_name>Id, and it is possible to include this in the $select if you want to access it from the odata response